# Density of $X_1 + X_2$ using convolution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convolution, density-function

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables continuously uniformly distributed on $[−1, 1]$ and $[0, 5]$, respectively.

Determine, with intermediate steps, the density of $X_1 + X_2$. To do this, use the convolution formula.

$$$$

I have done the following :

Let $Z=X+Y$. Then \begin{align*}\int f_Z(z)\,dz&=P(\{X+Y=z\})\\ & =P(\{X=t,Y=z−t\})\\ & =P(\{X=t\})\cdot P(\{Y=z−t\})\\ & =\int f_X(t)\, dt\cdot \int f_Y(z-t)\, dt\end{align*}

Is that correct so far ?

$$$$

EDIT :

Using the formula of convolution, do we have the following ?
\begin{align*}f_{X_1+X_2}&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt\\ &=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt+\int_{-1}^1f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt+\int_{1}^{+\infty}f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt\\ &=\int_{-\infty}^{-1}0\cdot f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt+\int_{-1}^1f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt+\int_{1}^{+\infty}0\cdot f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt\\ &=\int_{-1}^1f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt\\ &=\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{2}f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt\\ &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{-1}^1f_{X_2}(z-t)\, dt\end{align*}
Then we have that $f_{X_2}(z-t)=\frac{1}{5}$ if $z-t\in [0,5]$ and otherwise $0$, or not?

Comment: $P(X+Y = z)$ makes no much sense. However, you can use $E(P(X + Y \leq z \mid X)) = \int_{-1}^1 P(x + Y \leq z) f_X(x) dx$ and you need to write $P(Y \leq z - x) = F_Y(z-x) = \int_0^{\min(5, z-x)} f_Y(y) dy$ (assuming $z - x > 0$).

Comment: You need to split it into three intervals:  $-1 \lt z \lt 1, 1 \leq z \lt 4, 4 \leq z \lt 6$

Comment: Why do we take these intervals ? @MathLover

Comment: ok, see if my answer helps with the explanation

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is an *Iverson Bracket*. Namely, $\ds{\bracks{P} =1}$ whenever $\ds{P}$ is *true* and $\ds{0}$ *otherwise*.
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{5}{1 \over 5}{1 \over 2}\bracks{-1 < z - x_{2} < 1}\dd x_{2}} =
{1 \over 10}\int_{0}^{5}\bracks{z - 1 < x_{2} < z + 1}
\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 10}\bracks{\verts{z} < 1}\int_{0}^{z + 1}\dd x_{2} +
{1 \over 10}\bracks{1 < z < 4}\int_{z - 1}^{z + 1}\dd x_{2}
\\[2mm] + &
{1 \over 10}\bracks{4 \leq z <6}\int_{z - 1}^{5}\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{\bracks{\verts{z} < 1}\pars{z + 1} +
2\bracks{1 \leq z < 4} + \bracks{4 \leq z < 6}\pars{6 - z}\over 10}}
\end{align}
The above expression vanishes out whenever $\ds{z < -1\ or\ z > 6}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have $~X \sim U(-1, 1)$ and $Y \sim U(0, 5)$.

For distribution of $Z = X + Y, ~F_Z(z) = P(Y \lt z - x)$

Now as we must have $0 \lt y \lt z - x \lt  5$,

$(i)$ for $- 1 \lt z \lt 1, - 1 \lt x \lt z $

$(ii)$ For $1 \lt z \lt 4, -1 \lt x \lt 1$

$(iii)$ For $4 \lt z \lt 6$,
if $~-1 \lt x \lt z-5, 0 \lt y \lt 5$
if $~z - 5 \lt x \lt 1, 0 \lt y \lt z - x$

Please see the below diagram to understand better. Blue line is the upper bound of $z$ in $(i)$, the red line corresponds to upper bound of $z$ in $(ii)$ and the green line is the upper bound of $z$ in $(iii)$

[image]

Comment: So we have that $$F_Z(z) = P(Y \lt z - x)=\int_{\infty}^{z-x}f_Y(y)\, dy$$ right? How do we use now the intervals as for $z$ ? I got stuck right now.

Comment: If $-1 \lt z \lt 1, F_Z(z) = P(Y \lt z - x) = $  $ \displaystyle \int_{-1}^{z} \int_0^{z-x} f(x, y) \, dy \, dx$. Note $f(x, y) = \dfrac{1}{10}$

Comment: Why do  we have a double integral if we have just the random variable $Y$ at the left side ? That part is not clear for me. Could you explain that further to me ?

Comment: because $ \displaystyle F_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_Y(z-x) f_X(x) ~ dx$, $f_X(x) = \frac 12$ and $ \displaystyle F_Y(z-x) = \int_0^{z-x} f_Y(y) ~ dy$

Comment: You don't have to write double integral. Knowing $F_Y(z-x) = \frac{z-x}{5}$, you could write as $ \displaystyle \int_{-1}^z \frac{z-x}{5} \cdot \frac 12 ~ dx$

Comment: Why does it hold that $\displaystyle F_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_Y(z-x) f_X(x) ~ dx$ ? We have that $F_Z(z)=F_{X+Y}(x+y)=F_{X+Y}(x+(z-x))$, right ? How do we continue to get the above formula ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133859/discussion-between-math-lover-and-mary-star).